# Apache httpd error

Tags: httpd

On the control panel of the sharing hosting that I purchased, sometimes I go to see Last log lines containing errors.
Today I read this:

```
Sat, 18 May 2019 13:09:00 GMT [notice] - www.example.com - AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
Sat, 18 May 2019 13:09:00 GMT [notice] - www.example.com - AH00094: Command line: '/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
Sat, 18 May 2019 11:37:00 GMT [notice] - www.example.com - AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
Sat, 18 May 2019 11:37:00 GMT [notice] - www.example.com - AH00094: Command line: '/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

how should I interpret these lines? Is there anything I can do to investigate further?

Comment: I don't think those are errors.  That is the type of thing I usually see when I restart Apache.  What makes you think there is an error?

Comment: @stephen-ostermiller Since my hosting provider has a control panel where you can see the latest error logs.  That's where I found these logs.  suppose it is as you say, explain to me who restarted Apache?  because it wasn't me.

Comment: Your hosting provider runs Apache and  they are in charge of starting it, restarting it, and keeping it running.

Comment: Most probably you have a CRON job that regularly reboots the apache service. You can look for it in cpanel, or if you have access as root.